# What's the best way to pass state up top the component tree in app router?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm currently learning `Next.js` v13.5 and its latest `App router` architecture.

The problem is I'm a bit confused with its nesting and data exhange: My exact scenario is this: I've got a

```
Grandparent => Parent => Child
```

hierarchy. `Grandparent` and `Parent` are **nested layouts**. I want to be able to set the state in `Child` and have it reflected in `Grandparent`. However the docs state that [we can't just pass data from layout to components](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#layouts).

As an practical example think of the count of a shopping cart. I need to be able to show the total count of goods in the top right corner of the website's navigation bar. I am aware of `React Context` but I'm not sure if that's the proper solution here. I'm also open to using external state management libraries like [zustand](https://zustand-demo.pmnd.rs/) but I'm not sure if they are good fit here.

What would be the best way forward?

P.S.
In [Remix](https://remix.run/docs/en/main) I know we could use the `useMatches` hook ([docs](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/hooks/use-matches)) and get the data from a parent loader. What's the respective one in Next.js?

Comment: The "react way" of doing something like this is to define your state in Grandparent and pass the state setter functions down as props from where they'd be updated. But since you can't pass data down from layouts to pages, you'd have to rely on something like context to wrap the hierarchy you want this functionality in. Also note that to use context (or zustand etc) you'd have to make Grandparent a client component.

Comment: @AamirKhan keep in mind in next 13 you cant have it as a client component so no states are available there. Best bet would be to have a custom Layout within the layout.ts that holds the states for the navbar for shopping cart etc